# How to identify this SMD crystal oscillator or resonator?

Tags: oscillator, frequency, surface-mount, crystal, resonator

I need your help to identify this SMD crystal to fix a car ECU.

It is marked AR and has 3 pins on the bottom.

How can I find the frequency or specifications to order a new one or test this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since it has 3 pins, it is very likely to be a ceramic resonator instead of a crystal. The bigger issue is, why do you think it is broken and needs replacing? Just connect it into another oscillator to test it and the frequency.

Comment: uff, the manufacturer seems to have purposefully scraped off the markings. Are you *sure* this is an original part? That kind of shenanigans gets a component vendor kicked off automotive OEM supplier lists rather rapidly.

Comment: Exactly which car ECU is it?

Answer (score 4):

As @Justme says, this is a ceramic resonator. You can use this circuit from a [Murata datasheet](https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8801159970846/SPEC-CSTNE8M00GH5L000R0.pdf) to test the device and at determine the frequency:

[image]

Note that the chip must be a 74HC**U**04 (unbuffered version) for it to work reliably.

They don't typically die, however Murata cautions:

> 当製品は密閉構造ではありませんので、洗浄及び樹脂コーティングすることはお避け下さい。 Conformal coating or
> washing to the component is not acceptable, because it is not
> hermetically sealed.

Comment: It's an adblue ecu for Citroen/Peugeot cars and yes, it was covered in conformal coating causing the microcontroller from not receiving the timing signals. It does work but I'm hoping I can get spares by measuring the working specs before it fails. It is an original component in the adblue ecu circuit. So what I understand from your valuable insight is that it is a ceramic resonator. I assume the centre pin is ground and the outer pins must be + and - and can be tested with a multimeter with the Hz setting and powered on?

Comment: It's just a resonator, not an oscillator. It won't do anything unless you put it in a circuit such as the one I showed you (above) or maybe the original circuit. Some of the inexpensive frequency counter boards from China have a 'crystal tester' function which should work too. They were under $10 shipped but now more like $30 USD.